# Javascript wont load a specific part of the code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am messing around with javascript and I noticed that it wont load a specific line of code..

this one here...

```
function RoomClick(str, ID) {

    RoomSelected();
    _getRoomName = ID;

    document.getElementById(_getRoomName).className = "RoomStyleSelected"; 
}

 function RoomSelected() {
    var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("#Kati1 a")
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < divEls.length; i++) {
        //alert(divEls[i].id);
        _getRoomName = divEls[i].id;
        document.getElementById(_getRoomName).className = "RoomStyle"; //part where it doesnt load.
    }
}
```

```js
   function RoomClick(str, ID) {

            RoomSelected();
            _getRoomName = ID;
        
            document.getElementById(_getRoomName).className = "RoomStyleSelected"; 
        }

 
        function RoomSelected() {

            var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("#Kati1 a")
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < divEls.length; i++) {
                //alert(divEls[i].id);
                _getRoomName = divEls[i].id;
                document.getElementById(_getRoomName).className = "RoomStyle";
            }
        }
```

```css
.RoomStyle {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.RoomStyleSelected {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #00ff90;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}


#Kati1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    border: solid 2px #00ff90;
  
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
          <div id="Kati1">
          

            <a id="101" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,101)">101</a>
            <a id="102" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,102)">102</a>
            <a id="103" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,103)">103</a>
            <a id="104" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,104)">104</a>
            <a id="105" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,105)">105</a>
         
            <a id="201" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,201)">201</a>
            <a id="202" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,202)">202</a>
            <a id="203" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,203)">203</a>
            <a id="204" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,204)">204</a>
            <a id="205" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,205)">205</a>
         
            <a id="301" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,301)">301</a>
            <a id="302" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,302)">302</a>
            <a id="303" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,303)">303</a>
            <a id="304" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,304)">304</a>
            <a id="305" class=" RoomStyle" onclick="RoomClick(1,305)">305</a>
</div>
```

this snipped shows what it actually happens. when I want it only to make all green and then change the color of only 1.. how can I do that?

Comment: Always reference exactly not just "it wont load a specific line of code..", load is different from run/execute or as it appears here, "reference a document element".  No need to post the same code twice also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) selects elements by tag name, not by a CSS style query.

---

You are looking for [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead:

```
var divEls = document.querySelectorAll("#Kati1 a")
```